# how can i do for replace a part of a regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

For example i have this text:

select * from T1 ;

select * from T2 ;

select * from T3 ;

My objetive is replace the text by this other:

select * from T1_H ;

select * from T2_H ;

select * from T3_H ;

when i looking for the regexp, i put the next:
"from .* ; , but i whant replace only the part ".*" with the same text that has before plus "_H". How could i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) the part of the matching string so you can refer to it in the replacement.

Here are a couple of ways to do this:

1. replace `\(from\ \w*\b\)` with `\1_H`: here `\1` refers to the first group (the part between brackets). `\b` refers to the end of word (the place between *T1* and the space in your example).
2. replace `from\ \w*\b` with `\&_H`: here `\&` refers to the complete matched string.

Comment: Excellent explanation @juancho. The only missing piece is the meaning of `\w*`

Comment: Basic regular expressions for emacs are explained [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash).